Function from the real numbers to the powerset of an equinumerous set
The problem is stated as follows:
Assume that $|X| = |\mathbb{R}|$. Show that there exists a function $F :\: \mathbb{R} → \mathcal{P}(X)$, that satisfies the following conditions:
(C1): $$∀ \: a,b ∈ \mathbb{R} , \:\: a \neq b ⇒ F(a) ∩ F(b) = ∅.$$
(C2): $$∀ \: a ∈ \mathbb{R},\:\: |F(a)| = |\mathbb{R}|$$
(C3): $$\bigcup\nolimits_{ a∈\mathbb{R}} \: F(a) = X.$$
I don't really know where I even begin. I had an idea of creating a function, the values of which would be the intervals of real numbers, but since $X$ might not be a subsequence of real numbers itself, I can't do that directly. This intuitively feels like the right trick, but nothing comes to mind.

Well, since $|X|=|\mathbb R|$, there is a bijection between $X$ and $\mathbb R$, so you might as well come up with a solution for $\mathbb R$, and then you can use the bijection to carry the result over to $X$.

Yeah, that sounds reasonable. Although I'm still stuck as to how to map all real numbers to the their intervals.

Just find a function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ for which all fibers of $f$ have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ and define $F(a)$ to be $f^{-1}(a)$ (the fiber of $a$ under $f$) for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hint: $|\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}|$, so you can assume $X = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be bijections and $p$ be one of the two projections $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (it does not matter which one is used).
Then, define $F(a)$ to be $(p \circ f \circ g)^{-1}(a)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Conditions C1 and C3 will then be satisfied because $p \circ f \circ g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function. For C2, note that $F(a)=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(p^{-1}(a)))$ has the same cardinality as $p^{-1}(a)$ since $f$ and $g$ are bijections, which in turn has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ since it is either $\{a\} \times \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R} \times \{a\}$ depending on which projection is chosen for $p$. So, by transitivity of equality of cardinalities, $F(a)$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
